# How to use ELB and AutoScaling termination for long living connections

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I want to set up Autoscaling groups where we can launch and terminate instances based on the CPU load. But usually our connections stays for long like more than 8hrs sometimes even more than that. When I use NLB, the Deregistration delay is only supported till 3600sec and after that NLB will forcefully remove the connection which cause our long living connections to fail and autoscaling will terminate the instances as well.

How do I make sure that all my connections to the target group is processed after 8-10hrs and then NLB deregister or autoscaling terminate the instance?

I checked the ASG Lifecycle hooks and it allows connections only till 2hrs.

Is it possible to deregister the instances in target group after all the connections are drained and terminate the instance using ASG?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any good/easy way to do what you want to do.  What are the instances doing that can last up to 10 hours?

Depending on your work type, this is the best workaround I can think of, but it would probably involve a bit of rearchitecting.
1) design your application so that all data is stored off the instance is some sort of data tier (S3, RDS, EFS, etc).  When an instance is done doing whatever its doing, save that info to the data tier.  This way a user request can go to any instance and get the same information
2) The ASG decides to scale in
3) You have a lifecycle hook configured and a cloudwatch notification setup to be triggered when an instance enters the terminating:wait state which notifies the instance
4) The instance periodically sends a heartbeat to the lifecycle hook which can extend the hooks timeout for up to 2 days
5) Whenever the instance finishes what its doing, it saves the information out to the data tier mentioned in 1) and the client can connect to a new instance to get the information that was being processed on the old one

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/record-lifecycle-action-heartbeat.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/complete-lifecycle-action.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to use, Scaling CoolDown period.  By the default Scaling Cooldown Period is (300 Secs). you can increase the number. which will help to increase the scale in time.

Comment: This is wrong.  Cooldown affects the amount of time between simple scaling actions, it doesn't effect how long an instance would be deregistering for